# Fast way to implement pop_front to a std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

I'm using some classes and several utility methods that use std:: vector.

Now I need to use each frame a pop_front - push_back method on one of those classes (but they are all linked, and work together so I can't change only one).

Most of the operations are iterate over all element and push_back operations, so what I should do for the best work is: fork the repository of those classes and utilities, template everything, and use deque or list.

But this means a lot of code rewriting and a lot of testing that will make me miss the deadline.

So I need advice to write an efficient pop_front to a static-size vector (the size will not change).

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5565270/433685) a way:

```
template<typename T>
void pop_front(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
   vec.front() = vec.back();
   vec.pop_back();
   vec.front() = vec.back();  // but should this work?
}
```

And another idea should be:

```
template<typename T>
void pop_front(std::vector<T>& vec, already_allocated_vector vec1)
{
   vec1.clear();
   copy(vec.begin(), vec.end()-1, vec1.begin());
   copy(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec.begin());
}
```

What is the faster of these two solutions? Any other solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "the size will not change"?  After doing the pop_front, the vector will be the same size as before?  If so, should the last element be garbage?

Comment: the vector have the same size, because after a pop i suddenly do a push. each frame i made a pop and a push in the same method so before and after this method the vector is of the same size

Comment: Before worrying about speed, worry about **correctness**. All the speed in the world means nothing if the result you get is just plain wrong, and as far as I can tell, both your candidates are wrong. The first one should be named `pop_back_and_overwrite_front_with_penultimate`, and the second one should be named `invoke_undefined_behavior_and_pop_back`. (Writing to `vec1.begin()` is undefined because `vec1` is empty; you'd need to write `vec1.resize(vec.size() - 1)` instead of `vec1.clear()`.) When I'm dealing with vector operations, I sometimes draw a picture. Maybe that would help you, too.

Comment: heard of `std::deque`? is as good as `std::vector`, but can `pop_front()`

Comment: @SebastianMach I also looking for the same thing. unlike `std::vector`, `std::deque` is not continuous memory.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I would expect:

```
template<typename T>
void pop_front(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    assert(!vec.empty());
    vec.front() = std::move(vec.back());
    vec.pop_back();
}
```

to be the most efficient way of doing this, but it does not maintain the order of the elements in the vector.

If you need to maintain the order of the remaining elements in `vec`, you can do:

```
template<typename T>
void pop_front(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    assert(!vec.empty());
    vec.erase(vec.begin());
}
```

This will have linear time in the number of elements in `vec`, but it is the best you can do without changing your data structure.

Neither of these functions will maintain the `vector` at a constant size, because a `pop_front` operation will **by definition** remove an element from a container.

Comment: I think it is assumed that the order has to be preserved since `std::vector::pop_back` preserves order.

Comment: isn't it  better to include

    `vec.push_back(new_value)
    vec.shrink_to_fit()`

after?

Answer (score 9):

Since `pop_front()` only erases the first element, the direct implementation is this:

```
template <typename V>
void pop_front(V & v)
{
    assert(!v.empty());
    v.erase(v.begin());
}
```

Don't worry about speed for now. If you want to go back and optimize code, ask for dedicated project time.

Comment: sorry i don't understand your code it shoudn't keeo only the first element? i want to erase only the first element, shouldn't it be: v.erase(v.begin(), v.begin()+1); ?

Answer (score 2):

I also have a way... Not so good tho..

This looks like @0xPwn's solution, but he didn't reverse the vector the second time.
You will probably understand this code, so i will not explain it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
void pop_front(std::vector<T>& vec){
    std::reverse(vec.begin(),vec.end()); // first becomes last, reverses the vector
    vec.pop_back(); // pop last
    std::reverse(vec.begin(),vec.end()); // reverses it again, so the elements are in the same order as before

}
```

Comment: can it BE more inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

if you just try to erase the first element then in the function use:

```
if (my_vector.size()){ //check if there any elements in the vector array
    my_vector.erase(my_vector.begin()); //erase the firs element
}
```

if you want to emulate pop front for the entire vector array ( you want to keep pop out every element from start to end) , i suggest on:

```
reverse(my_vector.begin(),my_vector.end());  // reverse the order of the vector array
my_vector.pop_back();   // now just simple pop_back will give you the results
```