# Why doesn't std::vector::push_front() exist?

Tags: c++, vector

Since `std::vector::push_back()` exists, why doesn't `std::vector::push_front()` exist too?

I know there are others storage objects that work pretty much the same way and have an implementation of both `push_back()` and `push_front()` functions, but I was curious about the reason why `std::vector` doesn't.

Comment: `vector::push_front` couldn't be implemented efficiently; it would have O(n) complexity. Its absence discourages inefficient usage. If you really need it, there's `v.insert(v.begin(), value)`

Comment: Practically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5563952/560648 if you think about it

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Why are you answering in the comments section?

Comment: On the flip side, `std::list::iterator::operator-(iterator)` doesn't exist, but you can work around it with `std::distance` if needed. This is intentional; expensive methods should stand out.

Comment: You can directly create this #define push_front(v,val) v.insert(v.begin(), 1, val);

Comment: Is it really that hard for a vector to keep some extra space upfront? Say the vector's 0 starts at array's 10? Wouldn't that be similar to a vector leaving some extra space at the back? (which is why push back isn't that expensive).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't want to push_front on a vector ever. Adding an element to the front means moving every single other element in the vector one element back: O(n) copying. Terrible performance.

Comment: @Tyker Why?  If there is room at the end you don't need any more storage, you just have to move/copy everything back one.  That should just require one extra construction to construct that last element.

Comment: @Tyker: No. `push_front` has to move the existing objects, but it can move them in place by looping backwards.

Comment: @tyker if the size was 5 and the capacity 10 then pushing an element to the front would not cause a reallocation.  The only time that would happen is when the size equals the capacity and that is no different than push_back

Comment: If the vector has few (0-2) elements on average and is not expected to ever have significantly more, pushing at front might be a better choice if using std::deque would need a conversion to std::vector at a later point.

Comment: @NathanOliver it's been a long time, but responding to your comments for the benefit of others - pls don't take it personal:   you really don't want to move all elements forward, even if you don't have to reallocate.  Moving itself is very costly - O(N) as this responder mentioned.  And if you moved, it would invalidate existing iterators in an evil way.

Comment: In a memory of list , you can simply put an element at begin and update pointer to head ( similar to push , need not copy everytime )

Comment: Yes, I do want that. I use vector in an algorithm that requires pushing value at the front in some situations and despite this operation being terribly inefficient, it still fasted if done using vector which gives me a speed boost in all other parts of the algorithm.

Comment: Maybe I am not building an airplane

Comment: Counter argument: I actually *do* want to push an entry on the front of the vector.

Answer (score 15):

There's an important reason for that: std::vector<> is a continuous, single-ended array container. It allocates memory and starts writing the elements at the beginning of the allocated region. It usually allocates more memory than it needs to store all the current elements, so when you call push_back(), it writes the new element at the end and increments its element count. It's quick and efficient.

Push_front(), on the other hand, would require to somehow write the new element BEFORE all the current ones, at position [0] - however that's not trivial, since your array position [0] is occupied already. Push_front() would cause the whole array to be copied anew, so that its front can be modified. It would be an inefficient operation for which std::vector<> class is not designed.

You can still do it, of course, by calling

```
std::vector::insert(begin(), 1, val)
```

But it'll cause the whole array to be copied just to add a single element.

Comment: In modern c++, shifting elements in an `std::vector` is generally done (if move is `noexcept`) by moving them, not copying them.

Comment: Nope, moving refers to a different scenario that is unrelated to what is happening here. You can't add the first element to a contiguous array by "moving" the rest of the elements; copying will be involved one way or another.

Comment: so then, why the `vector::insert()` function exists?

Comment: @Fayeure, because even though they want to discourage it they can't deny there's a need for it. Personally, I don't care for avoiding syntactic sugar just because a language designer concluded it's a bad operation to run...they could instead have a compiler warning if they are so concerned about it.  As it is, people will waste time figuring out the hard way to do it, leave the code in, and forget that it's very inefficient.

Comment: @Dan I don't understand. Are you saying there 'is' a need for inserting at the front and it can't be avoided? If it can't be avoided why go for std::vector at all?

Comment: @ZoomIn, well maybe you have a vector that you push_back 1 million items, but every once in a great while you need to insert something at the front.  A single copy is expensive, but otherwise the vector is working great, so why change it?

Comment: @Dan Yup, makes sense.